# show hide div onclick jquery slowly when i click the button

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to  show hide div onclick jquery slowly when i click the button.this div will have result from database .i want it when it opened open with slow motion.

```
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
   <script src="script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script src="script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">

       $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#Button1").click(function () {
               $("#showdivslowly").slideDown('slow');
           });
       });

   </script>
</head>
```

```html
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div runat="server" id="showdivslowly" style="width:500px; height:200px; background-color:Blue" visible="false">Welcome</div>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1"  runat="server"  Text="Button" />

    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Instead of `slideDown('slow');` you can use `slideDown(1500);` where 1500 represent time in miliseconds

Comment: You cannot set a src attribute on the script tag and have text between script tags, it has to be one or the other

Comment: Call the show function inside the ajax operation success callback: `$.ajax( "example.asp" ).done(function(data) {//set the divs innerhtml and call show('slow')});`

Answer (score 2):

Use the [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function of jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#Button1").click(function () {
        $("#showdivslowly").toggle("slow");
   });
});
</script>
```

Toggle function is used to show the div if it is hide and to hide if it is visible.

You can also pass the time in seconds in instead of "slow".

Answer (score 2):

Few things:

You can't set a `src` in your `script` tag and then have `script` inside that - it must be closed:

Your buttons have a server generated ID (caused by `runat="server"`) - so you need to use the `ClientID`

Your `div` doesn't need to include `runat="server"` - I suspect you're only doing this for the `Visible="false` attribute. Instead, use CSS

`slideDown` also takes a time in milliseconds as a parameter

```
<script src="script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#<%=Button1.ClientID%>").click(function () {
           $("#showdivslowly").slideDown(2000);
       });
   });

</script>

<div id="showdivslowly" style="width:500px; height:200px; background-color:Blue; display: none;">Welcome</div>
```

Comment: Also note: He wants slow motion, so instead of `slideDown('slow')` he can use `slideDOwn(2000);`

Comment: i have error when i run this script system.web.ui.webcontrols.button does not contain adefinition for 'clientID'

Comment: @mohamedelhawary -- It's `ClientID` - capital C

Comment: it's worked but when it's sliddown return automatic to slidup again

Comment: what can ia do ?? any one help me

Comment: @mohamedelhawary -- You want it to slideup automatically?